I cannot make the formula spill dynamically in 2D
I need some fresh pair of eyes to look at the following Excel formula. I've got the following formula, where I cannot seem to make it spill down dynamically. The formula currently spills to the right correctly. If I change B5 and C5 to B5# and C5#, the formula does spill down (and to the right) correctly, but the values are incorrect. Can someone help me? Below is the formula. Note that B5# and C5# spill down the same exact number of rows with 1 column each and D$1# and D$2 spill to the right the same exact number of columns with 1 row each. I would appreciate your help. Thanks.
=LET(
deviceInstall, B5,
deviceRemoval, C5,
tcoStartDate, 'Deal Information'!B$6,
tcoEndDate, 'Deal Information'!B$7,
tcoStart, D$1#,
tcoEnd, D$2#,

installMonthsFrac, MAP(tcoEnd, LAMBDA(end,
    TRUNC(YEARFRAC(deviceInstall, end) * 12) +
    IF((DAYS(EOMONTH(deviceInstall, 0), deviceInstall) + 1) / DAY(EOMONTH(deviceInstall, 0)) = 1,
        0,
        (DAYS(EOMONTH(deviceInstall, 0), deviceInstall) + 1) / DAY(EOMONTH(deviceInstall, 0))
    )
)),

removalMonthsFrac, MAP(tcoStart, LAMBDA(start,
    TRUNC(YEARFRAC(start, MIN(deviceRemoval, tcoEndDate)) * 12) +
   IF(DAY(MIN(deviceRemoval, tcoEndDate) - 1) / DAY(EOMONTH(MIN(deviceRemoval, tcoEndDate), 0))=1,
      0,
DAY(MIN(deviceRemoval, tcoEndDate) - 1) / DAY(EOMONTH(MIN(deviceRemoval, tcoEndDate), 0))
))),

IF(
    deviceInstall >= tcoStart,
    IF(deviceInstall < tcoEnd,
        installMonthsFrac,
        0
    ),
    IF(
        deviceRemoval < tcoEnd,
        IF(deviceRemoval >= tcoStart,
            removalMonthsFrac,
            0
        ),
        IF(removalMonthsFrac < 12,
            removalMonthsFrac,
            12
        )
    )
)

)
Here is a mock table as was requested by one of the users. The above formula is in cell D5 and it should spill to the right and down.




B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I




1


01-Jul-24
01-Jul-25
01-Jul-26
01-Jul-27
01-Jul-28
01-Jul-29


2


01-Jul-25
01-Jul-26
01-Jul-27
01-Jul-28
01-Jul-29
01-Jan-30


5
01-Nov-24
29-Oct-29
8.000
12.000
12.000
12.000
12.000
3.903


6
01-Oct-24
29-Oct-29
9.000
12.000
12.000
12.000
12.000
3.903


7
01-Oct-24
29-Oct-29
9.000
12.000
12.000
12.000
12.000
3.903




It would help if you would mock up data and expected output in a markdown table format so we can copy paste and test your formula.

Is it possible to pull some of this out into helper columns? It would help parse and debug it.

@EngineerToast I started out with helper columns and tested out the formulas extensively. After that I combined all the formulas in a single formula. I keep version controls of the file so I can always go back to older versions with the helper columns.

@ScottCraner I added a markdown table. Thanks.

I think you overcomplicated things a bit by using multiple lambdas. Maybe this is easier adoptable: =YEARFRAC(IF(B3:B5>D1:I1,B3:B5,D1:I1),IF(D2:I2<C3:C5,D2:I2,C3:C5))*12
